# How to get data by one query

Tags: python, django

I have  two models question and option

```
class Question(AbstractStatusModel):
    pass

class Option(models.Model):
    option = models.TextField()
    is_correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How can I get a question with options and at least one correct option?

Comment: what is `AbstractStatusModel`?

Comment: In AbstractStatusModel there is the only status field

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the relationship:

```
Question.objects.filter(option__iscorrect=True)
```

Comment: It will return questions. You can then iterate through both correct and incorrect options.

Comment: If you mean like this "question.option_set.all()" then it will make another additional query.

Comment: So you can use `prefetch_related`